# Pattern matching across type classes

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, typeclass

I'm a Haskell newbie, so chances are I've missed something obvious...

I am trying to write a generic colour quantisation algorithm using ad hoc polymorphism. However, I'm having some trouble getting my data out with pattern matching (I've not actually got to the quantisation bit, yet).

I can't describe this succinctly, so here's a simplified version of my code which exhibits the problem:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Word

type ColourGrey = Word8

data ColourRGB = ColourRGB Word8 Word8 Word8
  deriving (Show)

data ColourStream = Greys   [ColourGrey]
                  | Colours [ColourRGB]
                    deriving (Show)

class Colour a where
  extractStreamData :: ColourStream -> [a]

instance Colour ColourGrey where
  extractStreamData (Greys x) = x

instance Colour ColourRGB where
  extractStreamData (Colours x) = x

someColours = Colours [ColourRGB 255 0 0, ColourRGB 0 255 0, ColourRGB 0 0 255]
someGreys   = Greys   [0, 127, 255]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ extractStreamData someColours
  print $ extractStreamData someGreys
```

The calls to `extractStreamData` fail with the following:

```
No instance for (Colour a1)
  arising from a use of `extractStreamData'
The type variable `a1' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Colour ColourRGB -- Defined at test.hs:20:10
  instance Colour ColourGrey -- Defined at test.hs:17:10
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `extractStreamData someGreys'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ extractStreamData someGreys
In the expression:
  do { print $ extractStreamData (someColours :: ColourStream);
       print $ extractStreamData someGreys }
```

This implies, to me, that Haskell can't infer which instance to use (the one for colours or the one for greyscale). Would that be right? If so, how would I go about fixing this?

---

**n.b.** The definitions of `ColourGrey` and `ColourRGB` are outside my scope of influence (they're part of an external library). So any suggestions need to be modulo these two types. I'd prefer not to mess about with `ColourStream`, either, as it's used in lots of other places.

The reason I need to access the "raw" lists is so I can work with things like `map`, etc. If there's a neat trick I've yet to learn which will make `ColourStream` iterable, then I suppose that would work... `</thinking aloud>`

Comment: What do you expect to happen if somebody executes `extractStreamData someColours :: [ColourGrey]`? (This is not snark. Giving a good suggestion about what to change will be hard unless you say.)

Comment: @DanielWagner That should never happen; the types will always match

Comment: The code I proposed is type-correct, so the types match. My question stands.

Comment: By the way, I really am not trying to be difficult. I think you are making a conceptual mistake here, and I'm trying to point it out and/or help you clarify what it is to us so we can make a good suggestion about how to proceed. Typeclasses are a pretty common source of such misunderstandings for beginners!

Comment: I suppose I'd expect it to cause a runtime error. (Sorry if I seem vague: Like I say, I'm very much a newbie...)

Comment: No offence taken: I appreciate the help :) What I ultimately want to do is match a stream of image colour data (either RGB or grey) to a palette (another stream, which *always* matches the colourspace of the image; which is why I say your example should never happen): So I try to extract the image and palette data and then run my algorithm through. Then, at the end, I reconstruct the `ColourStream`, for output.

Comment: Okay, I've written a tad about this ultimate desire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Haskell sees `extractStreamData` and realizes it's going to return some `Colour a => a`, but then you pipe that into show so it also realizes that `a` is an instance of `Show`, but after that there's no mention of `a`.

This means that Haskell can't figure out which type `a` should be. The solution is just to help out the typechecker and add some signatures

```
print $ (extractStreamData someGreys :: [ColourGrey])
```

like that.

However your typeclass instances are a bit... worrisome. What would happen if you passed you passed a `ColourGray` to the `ColourRGB` instance? Blowing up at runtime with little to know information is a bad response.

Remember that typeclasses is just a way of doing [really souped up] type based overloading. Really it looks like you want like what Daniel Wagner has or something like

```
translateRGB :: ColourRGB -> ColourGrey
translateGrey  :: ColourGrey -> ColourRGB
```

And then make your instances more like

```
instance Colour ColourGrey where
  extractStreamData (Greys x) = x
  extractStreamData (Colours x) = map translateRGB x
```

so that you just choose whether you want to treat your stream as `ColourGrey`s or `ColourRGB`s and work with that. Now when you use `extractStreamData` you're not trying to figure out what's in the stream first.

Comment: What if I don't know the type in advance?

Comment: @Xophmeister Then you'll have to pattern match and decide which instance to use, however you can't put that logic in a function since you'd want to return "some" `Colour a` but you wouldn't be sure which one. This is possible in Haskell, but requires quite a few hoops

Comment: I think, as @DanielWagner suggests, I'm making a conceptual error somewhere. My understanding was that I could use type classes to avoid having to write sets of pattern matching code which are almost the same...

Comment: @Xophmeister Well the problem is you're not really using typeclasses properly.. you have this type colourstream and it's basically `Either`. The problem is that you're instances are partial, which is a sure sign that they're wrong, you should make it possible to decode an arbitrary stream to a `ColourGrey` otherwise you're not using typeclasses properly

Comment: @Xophmeister Type classes seems like overkill in this case, where pattern matching would solve the problem easily. Why do you want to avoid pattern matching?

Comment: I think I get it. So type classes need to be closed; that makes sense. So is the proposal to have a function `ColourSpace -> [a]`, which just extracts the data using pattern matching?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, though I am not sure, that what you really want is something like this:

```
onColourStream ::
    ([ColourGrey] -> [ColourGrey]) ->
    ([ColourRGB ] -> [ColourRGB ]) ->
    (ColourStream -> ColourStream)
onColourStream onGreys onRGBs (Greys gs) = Greys (onGreys gs)
onColourStream onGreys onRGBs (Colours rgbs) = Colours (onRGBs rgbs)
```

If `ColourGrey` and `ColourRGB` share some operations -- say, a lightening operation -- and you want to use those operations on whichever thing you have, *then* you might make a type class and do something like this:

```
class Colour a where lighten :: Double -> a -> a
instance Colour ColourRGB  where lighten = ...
instance Colour ColourGrey where lighten = ...

onColourStreamPoly ::
    (forall a. Colour a => [a] -> [a]) ->
    (ColourStream -> ColourStream)
onColourStreamPoly f = onColourStream f f
```

Then you might be able to write something like `onColourStreamPoly (map (lighten 0.5))` or so to lighten all the colours by a half.

Edit: To respond to "What I ultimately want to do is match a stream of image colour data (either RGB or grey) to a palette (another stream, which always matches the colourspace of the image)": In that case, I think the lightest thing to do is simply use pattern matching. Let's assume you have some functions like:

```
matchPalette :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [Int]
myAlgorithm  :: [Int] -> [Int]
unmatchPalette :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
pipeline :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
pipeline xs ys = unmatchPalette (myAlgorithm (matchPalette xs ys)) xs

wholeShebang :: ColourStream -> ColourStream -> ColourStream
wholeShebang (Greys gs) (Greys gs') = Greys (pipeline gs gs')
wholeShebang (Colours rgbs) (Colours rgbs') = Colours (pipeline rgbs rgbs')
wholeShebang _ _ = error "Yikes! The colour stream and palette didn't match up."
```

Comment: Thanks: I think I understand what you're saying, but your code is well beyond me, at this point. My type class solution is looking more like, as you say, a conceptual misunderstanding!

Comment: Thank you for your addendum. I'd +1 you again, if I could! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here goes a simpler version of your program, sans compilations problems:

```
import Data.Word

type ColourGrey = Word8

data ColourRGB = ColourRGB Word8 Word8 Word8
  deriving (Show)

data ColourStream a = ColourStream [a]

extractStreamData (ColourStream stream) = stream

someColours = ColourStream [ColourRGB 255 0 0, ColourRGB 0 255 0, ColourRGB 0 0 255]
someGreys   = ColourStream ([0, 127, 255] :: [ColourGrey])

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ extractStreamData someColours
  print $ extractStreamData someGreys
```

Of course, I don't know how you will be using these definitions outside this simple example, so I'm not sure if it's good enough for what you're trying to do.