# Generic Functions in Haskell... I don't get it :(

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, generic-programming

I think my problem is that I'm confounding my very limited knowledge of Haskell's polymorphism with things like overloading and templating, from other languages. After my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712223/pattern-matching-across-type-classes), I thought I had a better grasp on the concepts, but having tried again, I guess not!

Anyway, I am trying to implement a generic distance function. That was straightforward enough:

```
euclidean :: Integral a => [a] -> [a] -> Double
euclidean a b = sqrt . sum $ zipWith (\u v -> (u - v)^2) x y
                where x = map fromIntegral a
                      y = map fromIntegral b
```

Now I want to apply this to two vector types (which, for the sake of argument, *cannot* be redefined):

```
type Vector1 = Integer
data Vector2 = Vector2 Integer Integer
```

After reading the answers to my previous question, I figured I would go with pattern matching:

```
d :: a -> a -> Double
d (Vector2 x1 y1) (Vector2 x2 y2) = euclidean [x1, y1] [x2, y2]
d a b = euclidean [a] [b]
```

This fails:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `Vector2'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for d :: a -> a -> Double at test.hs:11:6
In the pattern: Vector2 x1 y1
In an equation for `d':
    d (Vector2 x1 y1) (Vector2 x2 y2) = euclidean [x1, y1] [x2, y2]
```

So I figure I'll throw caution to the wind and try type classes again:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class Metric a where
  d :: a -> a -> Double

instance Metric Vector1 where
  d a b = euclidean [a] [b]

instance Metric Vector2 where
  d (Vector2 x1 y1) (Vector2 x2 y2) = euclidean [x1, y1] [x2, y2]
```

This compiles and works *when* the type you're feeding into `d` is known in advance. However, in my case, I have written another function, which calls `d`, where the type could be either (it's determined at runtime). This fails:

```
No instance for (Metric a) arising from a use of `d'
Possible fix:
  add (Metric a) to the context of
    the type signature for someFunction :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
In the expression: d c x
In the expression: (x, d c x)
In the first argument of `map', namely `(\ x -> (x, d c x))'
```

From my limited understanding of the answers to my previous question, I believe the reason for this is because my type class has holes in it, which leads the type inferencer into an indeterminable state.

At this point, I'm at a bit of a loss: neither parametric nor ad hoc polymorphism has solved my problem. As such, my solution was this mess:

```
someFunction1 :: [Vector1] -> [Vector1] -> [Vector1]
-- Lots of code
where d a b = euclidean [a] [b]

someFunction2 :: [Vector2] -> [Vector2] -> [Vector2]
-- Exactly the same code
where d (Vector2 x1 y1) (Vector2 x2 y2) = euclidean [x1, y1] [x2, y2]
```

This doesn't seem right. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first case, you have

```
d :: a -> a -> Double
```

which means the function can be called with any type, for example

```
d "blah" "blah"
```

but you are assuming it is of type `Vector2` in the implementation. So the compiler complains.

The second error is essentially the same thing. You have

```
someFunction :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

which again assumes `a` can take any type, but the implementation requires that it is of type `Metric` because you are calling the typeclass function. This is what the compiler is suggesting in the error message. So you want to use:

```
someFunction :: (Metric a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Comment: I'm glad it was such a simple omission. I was starting to go mad trying to understand where I was going wrong!... Thank you :)

Comment: A good idea is to (at first) leave out the type signature and see what the compiler deduces.

Answer (score 4):

compiller is telling you that you should restrict a in someFunction.
you are using d but type signature states that its valid for any a, but it should be valid only for a that has an instance of Metric.

The solution is to restrict a to be of class Metric:

```
someFunction :: (Metric a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Comment: Thank you :) You answered first, but @LukeTaylor's answer is "fuller": so +1 for you and tick for him.